# How do I prevent an Ice from freezing in faction base walls?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a huge base from bottom to the top I also made walls it almost finished I need water to protect it from TNT but how do I stop it from freezing the water?

Someone did there's duplicate of this question IT'S NOT there's nothing about on faction bases like on walls
[image]

Comment: I don't see how water freezing on a faction base is any different to water freezing in general. 1) Running water can't freeze 2) a solid block above the water will prevent it from freezing 3) Torches will prevent ice from forming/melt it when you place it. All of that is covered in the duplicate. Is there something special about a faction base that makes none of that true?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried putting a lily pad on top of the water? It makes it frostwalker-proof. I am sure it won't freeze the water in cold biomes...

Comment: It's a faction base protection walls I've seen tons of bases with water and they didn't have lily pad

Comment: Is your base in a cold biome?

Comment: No, it's not in cold biome

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a torch next to it. If that doesn't help, use lava near it!

Comment: It's a f'' faction base

Comment: how is that different?